# Using Qt signals and slots with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance, qt-signals

I have a class (`MyClass`) that inherits most of its functionality from a Qt built-in object (`QGraphicsTextItem`). `QGraphicsTextItem` inherits indirectly from `QObject`. `MyClass` also implements an interface, `MyInterface`.

```
class MyClass : public QGraphicsTextItem, public MyInterface
```

I need to be able to use `connect` and `disconnect` on `MyInterface*`. But it appears that `connect` and `disconnect` only work on `QObject*` instances. Since Qt does not support multiple inheritance from QObject-derived classes, I cannot derive `MyInterface` from `QObject`. (Nor would that make much sense for an interface anyway.)

There is a [discussion of the problem online](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq15-academic.html), but IMO the proposed solution is fairly useless in the common case (accessing an object through its interface), because you cannot connect the signals and slots from `MyInterface*` but must cast it to the derived-type. Since `MyClass` is one of many `MyInterface`-derived classes, this would necessitate "code-smelly" if-this-cast-to-this-else-if-that-cast-to-that statements and defeats the purpose of the interface.

Is there a good solution to this limitation?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that if I `dynamic_cast` a `MyInterface*` to `QObject*` (because I *know* all `MyInterface`-derived classes also inherit eventually from `QObject`, it seems to work. That is:

```
MyInterface *my_interface_instance = GetInstance();
connect(dynamic_cast<QObject*>(my_interface_instance), SIGNAL(MyInterfaceSignal()), this, SLOT(TempSlot()));
```

But this *really* seems like I am asking for undefined behavior....

Comment: How and where did you declare MyInterfaceSignal?

Comment: `MyInterfaceSignal` is declared as a *non-signal* protected pure virtual method in `MyInterface`, and then as a *signal* in derived classes. Thus, the compiler assures that the derived classes have the method, but it's up to the implementor to mark it as a signal. It's hokey, because I'm not *really* calling up the virtual call table from `MyInterface.MyInterfaceSignal`, but rather relying on the fact that the SIGNAL macro is--at the end of the day--just resolving to a `char*` method name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You found the answer yourself: the dynamic_cast works as you would expect. It is not undefined behavior. If the instance of MyInterface you got is not a QObject, the cast will return null and you can guard yourself against that (which won't happen, since you said all instances of the interface are also QObjects). Remember, however, that you need RTTI turned on for it to work.

I would also offer a few other suggestions:

- Use the **Q_INTERFACES** feature (it's not only for plug-ins). Then you'd work in terms of QObject and query for MyInterface using qobject_cast when it is really needed. I don't know your problem in detail, but since you know that all MyInterface instances are also QObjects, this seems to be the most sensible approach.
- Add a `QObject* asQObject()` abstract method to MyInterface and implement it as `{ return this; }` in all subclasses.
- *Having* a QGraphicsTextItem (composition) instead of *being* one (inheritance).

Answer (score 7):

You can declare MyInterface that takes a QObject in its constructor:

```
class MyInterface {
public:
                MyInterface(QObject * object);
    QObject *   object() { return m_object; }
    ...
private:
    QObject *   m_object;
};

MyInterface::MyInterface(QObject * object) :
    m_object(object)
{
    ...
}
```

Then in MyClass constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
MyInterface(this)
{
    ...
}
```

And you can connect the signal:

```
MyInterface *my_interface_instance = GetInstance();
connect(my_interface_instance->object(), SIGNAL(MyInterfaceSignal()), this, SLOT(TempSlot()));
```