# Multiple inheritance of QObject because of access to deleteLater() method

Tags: qt, inheritance, qobject

I use observer-observable pattern in my program. Everything worked before I had to change the code a little. If to be exact I changed the inheritance of IObserver class - right now it inherits QObject:

```
class IObserver : public QObject
{
...
```

I did it because of only one thing - I need deleteLater() method to be used in an observer, so I would be able to call implementation of virtual function deinitialization() of IObserver. Thus I could standardize every IObserver message handler.

The problem is, I already inherited QObject (indirectly) in some Observer classes. Like MainForm or AboutDialog. Everything is going fine until I try to call "connect" method in AboutDialog class.

What can I do? I really need this deleteLater() method since I can't use "delete this" in IObserver code - this will call IObserver destructor, not the MainForm or Storage classes for instance.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe some hint here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259728/using-qt-signals-and-slots-with-multiple-inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259728/using-qt-signals-and-slots-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really need this deleteLater() method since I can't use "delete this" in IObserver code - this will call IObserver destructor, not the MainForm or Storage classes for instance.

If you make your destructor virtual (and you should!) it will call the derived destructor just fine. But a problem is that destructing a object while it is handling some signal/slot might cause problems with the event loop. You would have to be very careful with `delete this` anyway.

> The problem is, I already inherited QObject (indirectly) in some Observer classes.

One way you could implement this, not sure if the best thought:

```
template <typename Derived>
class IObserver
{

    // Just to be sure: (C++11)
    static_assert(is_base_of<Derived, QObject>::value,
                  "must inherit from QObject when using IObserver");

    void deleteMe()
    {
        QObject* thisObject = dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this);
        // no need for check if thisObject equals null. static assert does this.
        thisObject->deleteLater();
    }

};

class MainForm : public IObserver<MainForm>, public QMainWindow
{
    // ...
};
```

I believe this pattern is called static polymorphism.

Comment: **If you make your destructor virtual (and you should!)**

I use `virtual void deinitialisation() = 0` in IObserver and believe that in implemented version all the resources will be released, so after calling the deinit I want to delete the object. Thank you for the example, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: The problem is if someone decide to `delete anIObserverPointer` it will not clear the resources of the derived class. Also, why not move the code from `deinitialization()` to `~IObserver()`? Much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Abandon inheritance of `QObject` for IObserver. Instead of that add such method to interface.

```
class IObserver : public QObject {
public:
   QObject *object() const = 0;
...
```

Then if implementation of interface inherits the `QObject` you will return `this` pointer from `object()` method. If implementation of interface doesn't inherit `QObject` you can simply return pointer to some simple QObject which will handle destruction of this object.
Then you can simply connect `deleteLater` for object returned by this method.

**Off topic**
Use of interfaces for observing in Qt usually is obsolete, slots and signals do this job perfectly and this is more flexible approach.

Comment: >job perfectly
Not in every case. When one need every possible signal to be written in log, one needs to connect these signal to log functions which is not standardised. Instead of making 20-30 functions-in-between I use 3-parameters generic function (the same idea as windows' SendMessage). Plus I can completely delete so of observers without damaging the app. Instead of calling specific function, for example, profileManager.getProfilesList, I call Send(OC_PROFILEMNGR, MC_GETPRFNAMES, &myStringList). So I don't care if there is any function like getProfileList or even if such manager exists.