# Using Qt5 new connect syntax with inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, signals-slots

I am trying to use the new connect syntax in some legacy code but came upon an architectural problem. So let's pretend I have a BaseReader class that looks like this :

```
class BaseReader : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    BaseReader();

  public slots:
    virtual void read(const fstream& myStream);
}
```

Then let's say I have some children classes like this

```
class Reader1 : public BaseReader
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    BaseReader();

  public slots:
    virtual void read(const fstream& myStream);
}
```

Some of the read work is done in the base class, some in the child class. I have about 4 classes that are switched around at runtime. I have a connectReaders function that looks like this :

```
void connectReaders(BaseReader* currentReader)
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(mustRead(const fstream&)), currentReader, SLOT(read(const fstream&)));
}
```

Now it is my understanding that if I use the new syntax I will connect to the base member function no the overloaded versions. Is that correct ? Is there any way to connect these signals using the new syntax without modifying the architecture ?  My example is very simplified and modifying that code would require a couple of months (including tests). It works the old way but I would like to take advantage of the new syntax. Any ideas ?

I have looked at these threads but they do not seem to offer a solution to this problem :

- This is the other way around:
  [Using Qt signals and slots with multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259728/using-qt-signals-and-slots-with-multiple-inheritance)
- I have read this but I am not sure I understand how the overload
  section applies: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

I have qt5.4.1, Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the advantage of the new syntax?

Comment: @tobi303: You get a compiler error vs. a runtime error, in case you specify a slot that doesn't exist. And it's faster, too. No need to look sieve through MOC-classes, doing string compares to find the designated target. Disadvantages? Too many to name, e.g. convoluted verbose syntax, in case you need to disambiguate between different overloads.

Comment: @tobi303: better error checking, probably faster and smaller code. You also no longer need the MOC compiler just for slots and connections - if your class has no signals, you can remove the `Q_OBJECT` macro from it, omitting the MOC pass and getting rid of the corresponding `*_moc.cpp` file. Faster compilation, smaller and faster code.

Comment: @ahesa: *"Now it is my understanding that if I use the new syntax I will connect to the base member function no the overloaded versions."* - I don't see any overloads. Are you referring to overridden members instead?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes sorry, a little "English is not my first language" mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Qt. The question here however, seems to be a C++ question.

When using a pointer-to-member to a virtual function in a base class, on a pointer/reference to a derived class, an override in the derived class will be called (if it exists).

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    void (Base::* pmf)() = &Base::f;
    Derived d;
    (d.*pmf)();
}
```

Will print "Derived", not "Base";

If a Qt signal calls your member function pointer with a derived object, the function override will therefore get called.

Comment: hmm good point, it might as well be a C++ question. I have not used pointers to function much. I was thinking assembler jump like commands or goto. I will make a small sample program using qt but the results should be the same regardless.

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem when using the new 'connect' syntax with virtual slots and base class object pointers. You're specifying the object instance (e. g. `currentReader`), and the specific method to be called will be resolved using this object's virtual methods table.

Comment: I was not arguing whether the new syntax was better or not.

Comment: @ahesa: I did not imply you were.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. Still a proper answer though I was thinking about this the wrong way.